# Netcat Chat bash script problems

Tags: bash, awk, terminal, netcat

I'm creating a sh script for a Chat using netcat.
This is the code:

```
#!/bin/bash

clear

echo
echo "-----------------------"
echo "| handShaker Chat 2.0 |"
echo "-----------------------"
echo

read -p 'Server or Client setUp? (s or c) > ' type

if [ $type == 's' ] || [ $type == 'S' ] || [ $type == 'server' ]
then
    read -p 'Port (4321 Default) > ' port
    if [ $port -gt 2000 ] && [ $port -lt 6500 ]
    then
        echo
        echo "Started listening on port $port."
        echo "Stream (Press ctrl + shift to end session) >"
        echo
        awk -W interactive '$0="Anonymous: "$0' | nc -l $port > /dev/null
    else
        echo "handShaker Error > The port $port is not a in the valid range (2000 ... 6500)."
    fi
elif [ $type == 'c' ] || [ $type == 'C' ] || [ $type == 'client' ]
then
    read -p 'Port (4321 Default) > ' port
    if [ $port -gt 2000 ] && [ $port -lt 6500 ]
    then
        read -p 'Destination IP > ' ip
        if [[ $ip =~ ^[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+$ ]]
        then
            echo
            echo "Started streaming $ip on port $port."
            echo "Stream (Press ctrl + shift to end session) >"
            echo
            awk -W interactive '$0="Anonymous: "$0' | nc $ip $port > /dev/null
        else
            echo "handShaker Error > Invalid IP Address."
        fi
    else
        echo "handShaker Error > The port $port is not a in the valid range (2000 ... 6500)."
    fi
else
    echo "handShaker Error > $type is not a valid keyword."
fi
```

But I have the following problems: the awk -W parameter doesn't seem to exist, and the program actually stops after running the client.
I'm using the macOS terminal.

Can someone help me to fix this bugs and to improve my script?

Comment: Does the script run without the `awk`? It seems to be an incorrect syntax used. Did you try commenting it out? and what is the output of `nc $ip $port` . Can you modify the line without the `awk` part with just `nc -l $port > /dev/null` ? I see no sense using awk there –

Comment: it works perfectly without awk. I commented the line and put instead nc -l $port and nc $ip $port. Now I want to use awk so I'll get the right output....

Comment: What output you need with `awk` from the `nc` command output?

Comment: Now I'm getting a message per line, but I want to have a thing like Friend: Message, every time someone from the other computer writes in the stream

Comment: It does not come within the scope of this question. Do ask a new one under `awk` tag with your input and expected output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your script has an incorrect & unnecessary usage of `awk` with `-W interactive` flags which are not defined in any of the flavours of `awk`. Removing it should solve your problem.

Also your script has a bunch of `bash` variables defined and used without double-quoting. Remember to [double quote variables prevent globbing and word splitting.](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC2086)